# Get Last conversation row from MySQL database table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database in MYSQL and it has chat table which looks like this.

[image]

I am using this query for fetching these records

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM `user_chats`
    WHERE sender_id =2 OR receiver_id =2
    ORDER BY id DESC
) AS tbl
GROUP BY sender_id, receiver_id
```

But my requirement is only 5,4 ID's records. basically my requirement id fetching last conversation in between 2 users. Here in between 2 & 3 user conversation has 2 records and we want only last one of them i.e. id = 5, here don't need id = 2.

So how we can write a query for that result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
 * 
FROM 
 user_chats uc 
WHERE
 not exists ( 
   SELECT 
    1 
   FROM 
     user_chats uc2 
   WHERE 
     uc2.created > uc.created AND 
     (
       (uc.sender_id = uc2.sender_id AND uc.reciever_id = uc2.reciever_id) OR  
       (uc.sender_id = uc2.reciever_id AND uc.reciever_id = uc2.sender_id)
     )
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

The following gets you **latest record** (assuming that the bigger `id`, the later it was created) **meeting your criteria**:

```
SELECT * FROM `user_chats`
WHERE (`sender_id` =2 AND `receiver_id` =3) OR (`sender_id` =3 AND `receiver_id` =2)
ORDER BY `id` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

which would be a good idea, if `id` is primary key and it rises along with rising value of `created`. Otherwise (if you are not sure that `id` rises when `created` rises) replace `ORDER BY` line with the following:

```
ORDER BY `created` DESC
```

Plus, in both cases, **put proper indexes** on: `id` (if it is your primary key, then there is no need to put additional index on it), `sender_id` and `receiver_id` (preferably composite index, meaning the single index for both columns), `created` (if you want to use `ORDER BY created DESC` instead of `ORDER BY id DESC` - otherwise there is no need for that).

Comment: @ypercube: Thanks for correcting `WHERE` clause. I do not agree with using order on `created` if `id` is a primary key and always rises with rising `created`. But I followed your edit and expanded my answer by including some comments + additional things.

Comment: You could also write the `WHERE` part with more compact code: `WHERE (sender_id, receiver_id) IN ((2,3),(3,2))`

Answer (score 0):

try `GROUP BY LEAST(sender_id, receiver_id), GREATEST(sender_id, receiver_id)`