# How to make a particular SELECT query

Tags: mysql, sql

First of all, I would like to apologize for the vague title of my question. It's very difficult for me to explain the situation, since I'm not an expert in SQL.

I need help in writing a query.

I have a table, called **HELLO-MESSAGES**, which contains several columns: *ID*, *From*, *To*, *Body*, *Sent* (with the data the message has been sent).

I have these rows:

1. **1, 345xxxxxxx, 339xxxxxxx, "Hey, how are you?", 12/1/2016 17:24**
2. **2, 339xxxxxxx, 345xxxxxxx, "Fine thanks, and you?", 12/1/2016 17:25**
3. **3, 345xxxxxxx, 340xxxxxxx, "The quick...", 12/1/2016 18:24**

What I would like to do is to display in a table, all different chats. If my telephone number is *345xxxxxxx*, I would like to display a table with the following layout:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><b>339xxxxxxx</b><br>Fine thanks, and you?</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>340xxxxxxx</b><br>The quick...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

For example, just like WhatsApp or any other IMs do. I want to display the number of the person I'm chatting to, and the last message sent in that chat. I've a really bad experience in programming queries: this is what I've produced so far:

```
SELECT * FROM 'HELLO-MESSAGES' WHERE 'From'='345xxxxxxx' OR 'To'='345xxxxxxx'
```

But it returns EVERY message, as expected!

Please help a beginner that does not like SQL so much :)

**EDIT**

```
SELECT *
            FROM (

                         SELECT MAX(d.id) AS max_id
                           FROM (

                                  SELECT df.id
                                    FROM ( SELECT xf.from
                                                , xf.to
                                                , MAX(xf.sent) AS max_date
                                             FROM `HELLO-MESSAGES` xf
                                            WHERE xf.from = '" . $_SESSION['ID'] . "'
                                            GROUP BY xf.from, xf.to
                                         ) mf
                                    JOIN `HELLO-MESSAGES` df
                                      ON df.from = mf.from
                                     AND df.to   = mf.to
                                     AND df.sent = mf.max_date

                                   UNION ALL

                                  SELECT dt.id
                                    FROM ( SELECT xt.from
                                                , xt.to
                                                , MAX(xt.sent) AS max_date
                                             FROM `HELLO-MESSAGES` xt
                                            WHERE xt.to = '" . $_SESSION['ID'] . "'
                                            GROUP BY xt.from, xt.to
                                         ) mt
                                    JOIN `HELLO-MESSAGES` dt
                                      ON dt.from = mt.from
                                     AND dt.to   = mt.to
                                     AND dt.sent = mt.max_date

                                ) q1
                           JOIN `HELLO-MESSAGES` d
                             ON d.id = q1.id
                          GROUP BY IF(d.from<d.to,d.from,d.to),IF(d.from<d.to,d.to,d.from)
                     ) q2
            JOIN `HELLO-MESSAGES` r
                ON r.id = q2.max_id
         ORDER BY r.sent DESC, r.id DESC
```

Is that right, @spencer7593? Thanks!

Comment: It's `MySQL` or `SQL Server`? They are different products and implement different extensions of the `SQL` language. Keep only the tag that matches the product you are using (and remove the other one). The generic [tag:sql] tag is ok.

Comment: It is MySQL (i'm using it with phpMyAdmin)

Comment: If this table grows to a large number of rows, a query that gets you the exact result you're after is likely to have performance issues. (One saving grace is that the query is filtering on one a specific phone number.) For this type of problem, I would strongly consider implementing an additional "latest message" table to hold the latest row for a conversation, and maintain that whenever a row is added to the `HELLO-MESSAGES` table.

Comment: If you are guaranteed that the `id` value of a row with a "later" message will always be larger than the `id` value of a row for an "earlier" message, your query could take advantage of that. Otherwise, you will need to do comparisons of the values in the `Sent` column. And there's a potential issue with two messages in the conversation that have the same value of `Sent`. Either way, the query is going to be fairly ugly.

Comment: @spenced7593 The ID is assigned automatically by the system. It is quite impossible that two messages are sent at the same time (please note that in the original Sent, seconds are included: 12/1/2016 17:45:52, for example).

Comment: You have no idea how fast my teenagers can send text messages!

Comment: Yes. That's the expression I'd add to the `GROUP BY` to fix the problem I identified in the queries I posted in my answer. I've also edited the query in my answer with that same change. I apologize for not catching that mistake earlier. (This is why I should *test* the query I give in my answers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I indicated in my comments, for a table with a large number of rows, to improve query performance, I would consider implementing an additional "latest message" table to be maintained along with the `HELLO-MESSAGES` table. But I won't delve into that, since that doesn't address the specific question you were asking. (But I suspect you'll be asking the question how to improve the performance of the query that gets the "latest message"... beyond ensuring appropriate indexes are available, and that table grows to a significant size.)

---

To get the latest message in each "conversation" sent *from* a specific a telephone number, you can use a query something like this:

```
SELECT df.id
     , df.from
     , df.to
     , df.sent
     , df.body
  FROM ( SELECT xf.from
              , xf.to
              , MAX(xf.sent) AS max_date
           FROM `HELLO-MESSAGES` xf
          WHERE xf.from = '345xxxxxxx'
          GROUP BY xf.from, xf.to
       ) mf
  JOIN `HELLO-MESSAGES` df
    ON df.from = mf.from
   AND df.to   = mf.to
   AND df.sent = mf.max_date
```

If there's more than one message with the same maximum value of "sent" for a given conversation, this query will return all of those rows.

A corresponding query can be used to get the latest message in each "conversation" that is received by a specific telephone number.

```
SELECT dt.id
     , dt.from
     , dt.to
     , dt.sent
     , dt.body
  FROM ( SELECT xt.from
              , xt.to
              , MAX(xt.sent) AS max_date
           FROM `HELLO-MESSAGES` xt
          WHERE xt.to = '345xxxxxxx'
          GROUP BY xt.to, xt.from
       ) mt
  JOIN `HELLO-MESSAGES` dt
    ON dt.from = mt.from
   AND dt.to   = mt.to
   AND dt.sent = mt.max_date
```

We can combine the results from those two queries, and return just the unique `id` value for those messages. We can combine the sets with the `UNION ALL` operator. (The MySQL optimizer generally doesn't do to well with 'OR' predicates; that's the reason for breaking the query into the two parts.)

```
SELECT df.id
  FROM ( SELECT xf.from
              , xf.to
              , MAX(xf.sent) AS max_date
           FROM `HELLO-MESSAGES` xf
          WHERE xf.from = '345xxxxxxx'
          GROUP BY xf.from, xf.to
       ) mf
  JOIN `HELLO-MESSAGES` df
    ON df.from = mf.from
   AND df.to   = mf.to
   AND df.sent = mf.max_date

 UNION ALL

SELECT dt.id
  FROM ( SELECT xt.from
              , xt.to
              , MAX(xt.sent) AS max_date
           FROM `HELLO-MESSAGES` xt
          WHERE xt.to = '345xxxxxxx'
          GROUP BY xt.to, xt.from
       ) mt
  JOIN `HELLO-MESSAGES` dt
    ON dt.from = mt.from
   AND dt.to   = mt.to
   AND dt.sent = mt.max_date
```

The set returned by this query will include the `id` values of the latest "sent" and "received" message in each conversation.

If we are guaranteed that the `id` value of a row for a "later" message will be greater than the `id` value of a row with an "earlier" message, we can take advantage of that, to deal with the issue of more than one "latest" message in the conversation; two or more rows with the same value of `Sent`.

We can use that to whittle down the results from the previous query to just the latest message in each conversation. We'll rerepresent the result of the previous query as `q1` in the next query:

```
SELECT MAX(d.id) AS max_id
  FROM (
         subquery
       ) q1
  JOIN `HELLO-MESSAGES` d
    ON d.id = q1.id
 GROUP BY IF(d.from<d.to,d.from,d.to), IF(d.from<d.to,d.to,d.from)
```

That get's the `id` values of the messages we want to return. We'll represent that result as `q2` in the next query.

```
SELECT r.id
     , r.from
     , r.to
     , r.sent
     , r.body
  FROM (
       ) q2
  JOIN `HELLO-MESSAGES` r
    ON r.id = q2.max_id
 ORDER BY r.sent DESC, r.id DESC
```

---

Putting that all together, we get a pretty ugly query:

```
SELECT r.id
     , r.from
     , r.to
     , r.sent
     , r.body
  FROM (

         SELECT MAX(d.id) AS max_id
           FROM (

                  SELECT df.id
                    FROM ( SELECT xf.from
                                , xf.to
                                , MAX(xf.sent) AS max_date
                             FROM `HELLO-MESSAGES` xf
                            WHERE xf.from = '345xxxxxxx'
                            GROUP BY xf.from, xf.to
                         ) mf
                    JOIN `HELLO-MESSAGES` df
                      ON df.from = mf.from
                     AND df.to   = mf.to
                     AND df.sent = mf.max_date

                   UNION ALL

                  SELECT dt.id
                    FROM ( SELECT xt.from
                                , xt.to
                                , MAX(xt.sent) AS max_date
                             FROM `HELLO-MESSAGES` xt
                            WHERE xt.to = '345xxxxxxx'
                            GROUP BY xt.to, xt.from
                         ) mt
                    JOIN `HELLO-MESSAGES` dt
                      ON dt.from = mt.from
                     AND dt.to   = mt.to
                     AND dt.sent = mt.max_date

                ) q1
           JOIN `HELLO-MESSAGES` d
             ON d.id = q1.id
          GROUP BY IF(d.from<d.to,d.from,d.to),IF(d.from<d.to,d.to,d.from)

       ) q2
  JOIN `HELLO-MESSAGES` r
    ON r.id = q2.max_id
 ORDER BY r.sent DESC, r.id DESC
```

---

EDIT: missing qualifier for ambiguous column reference

EDIT: fixed expressions in `GROUP BY` for q2. (The rows need to be collapsed/grouped by the distinct *combined* values of `from` and `to`. One approach to fixing that is to add an expression to the `GROUP BY`. That fix is applied to the queries above.

This answer illustrates one approach to returning the specified result. This is not necessarily the best approach. The usage of inline views (*derived tables* in the MySQL venacular) can impose a (sometimes significant) performance penalty.

Comment: Thanks you for the detailed answer! However, it gives me an error when I try to execute the entire query: `#1052 - Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous`. Thanks!

Comment: Yep. There's an unqualified reference in the q2 view query. `SELECT MAX(id)` should be changed to `SELECT MAX(d.id)`.

Comment: @PWhite: I'm looking at the query in my answer again, and I think there's a problem with the `GROUP BY` expression in q2. That will appear to "work" in some examples, but I think it does by accident. What that is supposed to do (what we want it to do) is collapse the set of rows from `q1` into a distinct set of conversation... unique set of `from`,`to`. Following the pattern already in use by the query, we'd  really need to add another expression... `GROUP BY IF(d.from<d.to,d.from,d.to),IF(d.from<d.to,d.to,d.from)`

Comment: I'll update my question with the full code to let you see if I undestood where to change!

Comment: @PWhite: I edited my answer. I think that fixes the problem. The purpose of the `IF()` expressions is to get common *combined* values of `from` and  `to` for each conversation.  A message from/to `(a,b)` is in the same conversation as a message from/to `(b,a)`. I think those `IF` expressions could be avoided by swapping the positions of `from` and `to` in one of the UNION ALL subqueries. (The value of one of those is going to be the phone number specified in the WHERE clause, so we really only need the other phone number. Grouping the rows by  that "other" phone number would be another way.

Comment: Thank you for the correction! I've edited the code. However, I've noticed it is a bit slower than the previous one. Is this true or is it just my impression?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100609/discussion-between-spencer7593-and-pwhite).

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for, I think is not that simple and you need to have good knowledge of sql. I think that the answer is in the following link:

[Get Last conversation row from MySQL database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427198/get-last-conversation-row-from-mysql-database-table)

Hope this helps you. 
Best regards !

Answer (score 0):

You can compare string with *LIKE* function. In your case:

```
SELECT * FROM `HELLO-MESSAGES` WHERE `From` LIKE "345%" OR `To` LIKE "345%" ORDER BY `Sent` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

See more: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. I know the full number, but this query will return EVERY message for EVERY chat. I want only the **last message for every chat**. Thanks!

Comment: I've edited the query, it will work if you are using MySql.

Comment: The query does not work. It returns only one message from one chat. I have other chats that are not displayed with that query.